Wordpress block based payment gateway showing - Getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when printing html through js
I am updating existing payment gateway to support latest version of wordpress and also to make compitable with block-based checkout. I want to display multiple payment option list under my payment gateway but when i use some html in js it throws syntax error. Plese help me as i am new to block-based checkout. below are my js and wordpress code
JS CODE:---
    const settings = window.wc.wcSettings.getSetting( 'casheer_data', {} );
    const Label = ( props ) => {
        const { PaymentMethodLabel } = props.components
        return <PaymentMethodLabel text={ label } /> /* in this line i am getting erro */
    }
    const Content = () => {
        return window.wp.htmlEntities.decodeEntities( settings.description || '' );
    };


Below is my wordpress register script function

            wp_register_script(
            'casheer-blocks-integration',
            plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'checkout.js',
            [
                'wc-blocks-registry',
                'wc-settings',
                'wp-components',
                'wp-element',
                'wp-data',
                'wp-html-entities',
                'wp-i18n',
            ],
            null,
            true
        );
        if( function_exists( 'wp_set_script_translations' ) ) {            
            wp_set_script_translations( 'casheer-blocks-integration');
            
        }
        wp_localize_script( 'casheer-blocks-integration', 'myCustomGatewayData', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            // Other data
        ));     


Woo-commerce is still working on some common bugs. Even now, many of the payment gateways in woo-commerce do not support the block based process. We will release our new version as soon as possible. Which can lead to less and less trouble for all people. For now you can understand that the current version of woo-commerce is not stable for block-based checkout.
